# How to use FindRoot to solve Hypergeometric1F1 imaginary number solution？

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I want to use **`FindRoot`** to solve **`Hypergeometric1F1`** imaginary number solution.

First of all, I try to use **`NSolve`** to solve the equation, and have made the following attempts:

```
NSolve[x^2 + 1 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 0. - 1. I}, {x -> 0. + 1. I}} *)
```

However, **`NSolve`** cannot solve the system at present.

```
NSolve[0 == Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, 2/x], x]
```

Therefore, I want to use **`FindRoot`** to solve the imaginary number solution of the function.

At present, I have tried **`ReImpPlot`**, but the effect is not very good.

How can I use **`FindRoot`** to solve all imaginary solutions of **`Hypergeometric1F1`** function? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [countably infinitely many](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountablyInfinite.html) zeros of your $f(x)$, which we can enumerate as follows.

For small $x$, your function is approximated by $e^{1/x} x \sinh(1/x)$:

```
f[x_] = Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, 2/x];
g[x_] = E^(1/x) x Sinh[1/x];

ReImPlot[{f[I x], g[I x]}, {x, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

This approximation gives excellent starting points for numerical root-finding: for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ we have $g[i/(n\pi)]=0$, and find the $n^{\text{th}}$ zero of $f$ from this starting point:

```
zf[n_Integer /; n != 0] := x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, I/(n*π)}]

Array[zf, 10] // Chop
(*    {0. + 0.458929 I, 0. + 0.173708 I,
       0. + 0.110616 I, 0. + 0.0815787 I,
       0. + 0.0647315 I, 0. + 0.0536934 I,
       0. + 0.0458896 I, 0. + 0.0400755 I,
       0. + 0.035574 I, 0. + 0.0319845 I}    *)
```

Much higher zeros can be found in this way:

```
zf[10^6]
(*    0. + 3.1831*10^-7 I    *)
```

For added stability we can extract more factors from $g(x)$ to regularize your $f(x)$ before nulling: notice that $g(i/y) y e^{i y} = \sin y$ with zeros at $y_n=n\pi$, and further that $f(i/y) y e^{i y}\in\mathbb{R}$ if $y\in\mathbb{R}$; and hence

```
zf2[n_Integer /; n != 0] :=
  I/y /. FindRoot[Re[f[I/y] E^(I y) y], {y, n*π}]

zf2[10^6]
(*    0. + 3.1831*10^-7 I    *)

ReImPlot[{f[I/y] E^(I y) y, Sin[y]}, {y, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you restrict the domain, then [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve) can find solutions:

```
NSolve[0 == Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, 2/x] && Abs[x]<1, x]
```

> {{x->0. -0.0227961 I},{x->0. -0.0290547 I},{x->0. -0.035574 I},{x->0. +0.035574 I},{x->0. -0.0400755 I},{x->0. -0.0458896 I},{x->0. +0.0458896 I},{x->0. +0.0536934 I},{x->0. -0.458929 I},{x->0. +0.458929 I}}